# Why do some users have a dotted border?

Tags: bug, design

I noticed this:

[image]

As you can see, some users have a dotted border around their profile picture. I recently changed my profile picture, but Renan didn't, as far as I know. This really isn't something on the picture, I checked, it's in the stylesheet of the website (see below).

I can't find a logic in who has the border and who hasn't. It's the same all the time though.

---

Users with a dotted border have a somewhat malformed profile page: the user's info starts below the image. Have a look at [my profile](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17592/camil-staps) for example.

[image]

**This has been fixed. The dotted borders still appear though.**

---

More users: [I rakshith](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/19926/i-rakshith), [Nick Rosencrantz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/10456/nick-rosencrantz), [Jeremy Tunnell](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/19318/jeremy-tunnell), [angelatlarge](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/19941/angelatlarge), [Tom L.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11970/tom-l), [Brian Drummond](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/16324/brian-drummond) (after he changed his avatar, I believe)

---

This is EE-specific. I can't find any picture on WordPress Answers or TeX with the dotted border.

---

I took a look at the HTML, and found that the users with dotted border are in a `<div>` with class `gravatar-wrapper-32`. The other users are in a `<div>` with no class at all. The CSS (`border: 1px dotted rgb(195, 181, 156);`) is linked to the class `gravatar-wrapper-32`.

Comment: Oh, damn, you have found the secret labeling mechanism.

Comment: User [Nick Rosencrantz](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/10456/nick-rosencrantz) and User [Jeremmy Tunnell](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/users/19318/jeremy-tunnell)

Comment: You'll know when you get that knock on your door in the middle of the night.  Pack some warm clothes.  Siberia is still cold this time of year.

Comment: You mean you don't really look like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary solution is to add a UserScript to your browser, like this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Remove dotted border on EE.SE
// @namespace   http://*electronics.stackexchange.com/*
// @version     1.0
// @include     http://*electronics.stackexchange.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

// .gravatar-wrapper-32 is for small pictures like under a question / answer
// .gravatar-wrapper-48 is for somewhat bigger pictures like on the users list
// .gravatar-wrapper-128 is for the profile picture
$('.gravatar-wrapper-32, .gravatar-wrapper-48, .gravatar-wrapper-128').css({
    border: '0'
});
```

Comment: But if we do that, then everyone will be equal.  How are we supposed to know the better people from the ones with the dotted borders then?

Comment: @OlinLathrop you are mistaken. The people with the dotted borders are better!

Comment: Wow. The "problems" some people have. Isn't there something better that needs solving?

Comment: @angelatlarge it was worse when the profile page wasn't malformed too. And still it's weird.

Answer (score 1):

That's why - see the `border` rule?

```
.gravatar-wrapper-32 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px dotted #BBBBBB;
    height: 32px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
}
```

Comment: I can see that, however, I can't see the logic in which users have `.gravatar-wrapper-32` and which not.

Answer (score -2):

This is a wild guess.  I notice that the pictures with borders seem to have some sharpening applied to the small versions.  Since you upload a single larger size picture, SE (or that silly gravater service they use) must be doing the sharpening.  My guess is that what appears as a dotted line is a artifact of the sharpening algorithm that has a problem dealing with the edges of pictures.  Uploaded pictures can themselves often have a unintended one-pixel border, which together with a sloppily written sharpening algorithm could make a mess.

Could be a feature though, I don't really know.  Perhaps they are planning to celebrate SE on postage stamps.

Comment: It isn't gravatar, it's in the CSS (stylesheet)..

Comment: @Camil: There does seem to be some correllation to images that are sharpened though.  Maybe that cause that particular style sheet to get used?

Comment: That might be, but I cannot answer that question.